# multipleinput directories in hadoop

Tags: hadoop

So, I have two different directories.. which i want to process differently...
For which I have to mappers for the job..

Data1
Data2

and in my driver.. I add the following:

```
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path( args[0]), 
                                    TextInputFormat.class, 
                                    Data1.class);


    MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[1]),
                                TextInputFormat.class,
                                Data2.class);
```

But what I now want is to just select two files from it..

So.. usually this is how we would do this

```
FileInputFormat.addInputPaths(job,"Data1/part-00000,Data1/part-00000");
```

But.. how do i specify specific files in MultiInputs object.

Basically.. two mappers.. processing two different inputs... but I want to specify which files in thsoe two directories to read for processing by mappers.?
How do i do this in hadoop?

Answer (score 0):

Call addInputPath twice:

```
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path("Data1/part-00000"),
                            TextInputFormat.class,
                            Data2.class);
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path("Data1/part-00002"),
                            TextInputFormat.class,
                            Data2.class);
```

The effect of this call is merely to "Add a Path with a custom InputFormat to the list of inputs for the map-reduce job.". It should be okay if some paths have the same InputFormat.

If you have many such files, you could put them in a list and loop over them to add them all.

[FileInputFormat also has a setInputPathFilter method](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/FileInputFormat.html). I actually don't exactly how MultipleInputs works in unison with FileInputFormat, but you could try implementing a PathFilter class with whatever path filtering logic you would like, which might be better if you can select all the intended parts by simply using regex or simple rules.